# How do I change date in the 2nd column in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame called School_Behavior.
I have a column "sex" with responses as

- 1 for male,
- 2 for female.

How do I only change the 1's and 2's in this column?

Comment: change to what value?

Comment: I want to change the responses of "1" to instead be "Male" and "2" to be "Female"

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2359523) with your question to aid with answers.

Answer (score 0):

We can use do that with indexing.  Assuming that the 'sex' is `character` column, convert it to `numeric`, use that as index to pass the string vector for replacement

```
df1$Sex <- c("Male", "Female")[as.numeric(df1$Sex)]
```

---

```
df1 <- data.frame(Sex = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```